# Cache key length in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

I was investigating the MVC3 source and came across the following (in OutputCacheAttribute.cs) which is called when generating a key to use for output caching:

```
        // The key is typically too long to be useful, so we use a cryptographic hash
        // as the actual key (better randomization and key distribution, so small vary
        // values will generate dramtically different keys).
        using (SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create()) {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uniqueIdBuilder.ToString())));
        }
```

The comment says that the use of a hash is required because "The key is typically too long to be useful". Can anyone shed light on this and recommend a maximum length for cache keys in asp.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length doesn't actually matter as it is converted to a hash. 
This applies to MVC and ASP.NET.

[Maximum length of cache keys in HttpRuntime.Cache object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330621/maximum-length-of-cache-keys-in-httpruntime-cache-object)